# How can I resize the dompdf size to ID card size in laravel

Tags: laravel, dompdf

I am trying to generate id card size of the view I have but, the content of the page is getting divided into different ID card size. how can I display all the view data into one card?

I am able to generate the size of the card but not getting al the contents inside it.

[image: output]

Comment: Any update or you solved the issue?

Comment: I had to fix the view and it was ok I used setPapersize('c3) and it worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**
I had to re-design the view and used

```
setPaper('catalog #10 1/2 envelope','portrait')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the size using `defaultPaperSize` attribute in config file or using `setPaper()` method, example from github document

```
PDF::loadHTML($html)->setPaper('a4', 'landscape')->setWarnings(false)->save('myfile.pdf')
```

custom size

```
$customPaper = array(0,0,360,360);
$dompdf->setPaper($customPaper);
```

Comment: But I will get the whole thing in one a4 paper but I need everything in ID card size. is that possible?

Comment: 36o is bigger than what I want to do I want everything in (0,0,153.071
243.78) in this dimension if possible

Comment: @AnishAnsari put size you required, I have only given an example.

Comment: When putting the size required I am getting the output as I have described in the question. any other solution will be very helpfull

Comment: @AnishAnsari check https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Usage#setpaper

Comment: @AnishAnsari Did you got the idea or having still issue?

Comment: I got the idea and I have already tried it but not getting the view in the defined dimension I want :(

Comment: it's working perfectly. I can generate any size of pdf.

Comment: working perfectly, only to note that the numeric value is in the unit of `point`. we only have to search google to convert millimeter to point, [click here](https://www.google.com/search?q=millimeter+to+point).